# Fill 100% of viewport with ignoring parent's side paddings but respecting the vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

### Requirements

1. `.Child` must fill 100% of viewport in despite of `.Parent` has side paddings.
2. `.Parent`'s side paddings are **unknown at advance** for the `.Child` (assume that the `.Child` is a reusable component which does not know about environment in which it used)
3. The scrollbar width is broswer-dependent, thus it's width is **unknown at advance and could not be hard-coded**.
4. `.Child` must be fully visible in length.

### Solution attempt

```css
.Parent {
  background: #BBDEFB;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.Child {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(-0.5*(100vw - 100%));
  /* Child does not know that `Parent's` paddings are 20px */
  height: 40px;
  background: #FF8F00;
  border: 5px solid #283593;
}

.Dummy {
  height: 1000px;
  background: #E1BEE7;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="Child"></div>
  <div class="Dummy"></div>
</div>
```

The `Child`'s left and right borders are not visible.
I suppose the cause is a scrollbar.

Can we respect the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not satisfy the requirement that the parent has side "padding". I interpreted that loosely in this answer.

If you don't need to use "vw" units you don't need to worry about the scrollbar width. Personally, I consider "100vw" and "100vh" as code smells now because of all the potential issues with scrollbars and mobile browser chrome.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr 20px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.Child {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  border: 5px solid #283593;
}

.Dummy {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="Child"></div>
  <div class="Dummy"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I selected your solution because it is relatively simple but flexible. Although the `.Parent` has not paddings in your solution, you get same effect vis `grid-template-columns`. Subjectively, this solution could be used in real projects.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be completely solved with CSS only. You can center it and make it the viewport width, but you can't determine the OS without JS, because the scroll bar varies relative to the OS and browser.

*Here are the scrollbar sizes tested in each browser:*

- OSX (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) - 15px
- Windows XP (IE7, Chrome, Firefox) - 17px
- Windows 7 (IE10, IE11, Chrome, Firefox) - 17px
- Windows 8.1 (IE11, Chrome, Firefox) - 17px
- Windows 10 (IE11, Chrome, Firefox) - 17px
- Windows 10 (Edge 12/13) - 12px

**So possible solution can be:**

1. Set the width of the Child element as (100vw - scrollbar width)
2. Center this element on the page.
3. Detect OS and add the relative class to the body element
4. Calc the width of the child element as for the windows os by default
5. Change it on Mac and in Edge browser

```js
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Win') != -1) {
  document.body.classList.add('win');
} else if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Mac') != -1) {
  document.body.classList.add('mac');
}
```

```css
.Parent {
  background: #BBDEFB;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.Child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100vw - 17px);
  height: 50px;
  background: #FF8F00;
  border: 5px solid #283593;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
/* MacOs */
.mac .Child {
  width: calc(100vw - 15px);
}
/* Edge */
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
 .Child {
    width: calc(100vw - 12px);
  }
}
.Dummy {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #E1BEE7;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="Child"></div>
  <div class="Dummy"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be achieved via this

```
.Child {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #FF8F00;
    border: 5px solid #283593;
    box-sizing: border-box
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

this solution may be help, i add **"display:block"** in **.child** ,add **width:auto** & remove **margin-left**.

```css
.Parent {
  background: #BBDEFB;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.Child {
  width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  margin:0 -20px;

  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  background: #FF8F00;
  border: 5px solid #283593;
}

.Dummy {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #E1BEE7;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="Child"></div>
  <div class="Dummy"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry but in your snippet, the `.Child` does not fill the viewport (1st requirement). There is visible `.Parent`'s light blue background on the left and right sides of the `Child`. Would you please to correct your solution?

Comment: Sorry, now I understand you want orange "div" in full width. I change some CSS ".child" class you may check it.

Comment: I am very sorry to reject your help twice, but now your solution does not satisfy to 2nd requirement and even still does not satisfy to 1st one. In the `.Child` you suggested: `width: calc(100vw - 40px); margin:0 -20px;`, which implies that we know that the `.Parent`'s paddings are `20px`. However according to 2nd requirement, we don't know `.Parent`'s paddings at advance because as reusable component `.Child` could be used in any other parent element. Next, there still a small gap between right border of `.Child` and right edge of the viewport. It means `.Child` does not fill the viewport.